# Is there a way to ask an IF inside of an IF using numerical equations in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying for a while now and cannot seem to get my excel formula to work. Examples online show me how to display a result for the IF statements using letters or sentences as results but I cannot find a resource online that guides me in how to get the proper result using numerical equations. I've tried multiple ways of formatting this formula but nothing seems to work. As soon as I place the first parenthesis for the inner IF it shows me that I have an error. Please help!
[Excel Doc Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjnzC.png)

Comment: you need to post your formula out and explain the logic and demonstrate the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is wrong. You are trying to compare value and an array. "O4>O5:O8"
You compare a cell with another cell.

```
=IF(E9=C2,E4,IF(O4>(MAX(O5:O8),E4+1,E4))
```